# Difference between ESP8266 SMING TCP sendString() and writeString()

Tags: tcp, esp8266, sming

I am using ESP8266 with the [SMING framework](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming).

I found this sample code in the [Telnet_TCPServer_TCPClient example](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/develop/samples/Telnet_TCPServer_TCPClient/app/application.cpp).

```cpp
bool tcpServerClientReceive (TcpClient& client, char *data, int size)
{
   debugf("Application DataCallback : %s, %d bytes \r\n", client.getRemoteIp().toString().c_str(),size );
   debugf("Data : %s", data);
   client.sendString("sendString data\r\n", false);
   client.writeString("writeString data\r\n",0 );
   if (strcmp(data,"close") == 0)
   {
      debugf("Closing client");
      client.close();
   };
   return true;
}
```

What is the difference between `sendString()` and `writeString()` in this sample code? It seems like there is no difference. The outcome is to send string data over to the other TCP party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client object used in the example is an instance of `TcpClient` which in turns is a derived class from `TcpConnection` object. `TcpClient` does have a [`.sendString`](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/develop/Sming/SmingCore/Network/TcpClient.cpp#L72) method and the [`.writeString`](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/develop/Sming/SmingCore/Network/TcpConnection.cpp#L136) method is a method of the class `TcpConnection` (the parent class of `TcpClient`)

In fact there are two overloaded methods for `.writeString`

So, having all that information out of the way, basically `.sendString` does this (inside that method it calls the [`.send`](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/develop/Sming/SmingCore/Network/TcpClient.cpp#L77) method):

```
if (state != eTCS_Connecting && state != eTCS_Connected) return false;

if (stream == NULL)
    stream = new MemoryDataStream();

stream->write((const uint8_t*)data, len);
asyncTotalLen += len;
asyncCloseAfterSent = forceCloseAfterSent;

return true;
```

and the [`.write`](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/develop/Sming/SmingCore/Network/TcpConnection.cpp#L146) method does this:

```
   u16_t available = getAvailableWriteSize();
   if (available < len)
   {
       if (available == 0)
           return -1; // No memory
       else
           len = available;
   }

   WDT.alive();
   err_t err = tcp_write(tcp, data, len, apiflags);

   if (err == ERR_OK)
   {
        //debugf("TCP connection send: %d (%d)", len, original);
        return len;
   } else {
        //debugf("TCP connection failed with err %d (\"%s\")", err, lwip_strerr(err));
        return -1;
   }
```

So from the looks of it one will be async (`.sendString`) and the other won't (`.writeString`).